# Synonym handling replacement issue with UDF in Apache Spark

Tags: dataset, apache-spark

We are currently working to replace the synonyms of certain words in a Row.

We are facing the problem as shown below.

```
     List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
        RowFactory.create(0, "Allen Armstrong nishanth hemanth Allen"),
        RowFactory.create(1,"shivu Armstrong nishanth"),
        RowFactory.create(2,"shree shivu DeWALT"));

      StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
      new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false,
        Metadata.empty()),
      new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false,
        Metadata.empty()) });
      Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);


      List<Row> data2 = Arrays.asList(
        RowFactory.create("Allen", "Apex Tool Group"),
        RowFactory.create("Armstrong","Apex Tool Group"),
        RowFactory.create("DeWALT","StanleyBlack"));

      StructType schema2 = new StructType(new StructField[] {
      new StructField("label2", DataTypes.StringType, false,
        Metadata.empty()),
      new StructField("sentence2", DataTypes.StringType, false,
        Metadata.empty()) });
      Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema2);

      UDF2<String, String, Boolean> contains = new UDF2<String, String, Boolean>() {
             private static final long serialVersionUID = -5239951370238629896L;

             @Override
             public Boolean call(String t1, String t2) throws Exception {
                 return t1.contains(t2);
             }
         };
         spark.udf().register("contains", contains, DataTypes.BooleanType);

         UDF3<String, String, String, String> replaceWithTerm = new UDF3<String, String, String, String>() {
             private static final long serialVersionUID = -2882956931420910207L;

             @Override
             public String call(String t1, String t2, String t3) throws Exception {
                 return t1.replaceAll(t2, t3);
             }
         };
         spark.udf().register("replaceWithTerm", replaceWithTerm, DataTypes.StringType);


         Dataset<Row> joined = sentenceDataFrame.join(sentenceDataFrame2, callUDF("contains", sentenceDataFrame.col("sentence"), sentenceDataFrame2.col("label2")))
           .withColumn("sentence_replaced", callUDF("replaceWithTerm", sentenceDataFrame.col("sentence"), sentenceDataFrame2.col("label2"), sentenceDataFrame2.col("sentence2")));
         joined.show(false);
```

**Input**

Allen Armstrong nishanth hemanth Allen
shivu Armstrong nishanth
shree shivu DeWALT

Replacement of words
The word in LHS has to replace with the words in RHS given in the input sentence
Allen => Apex Tool Group
Armstrong => Apex Tool Group
DeWALT => StanleyBlack

```
       Output

      +-----+----------------------------------+---------+---------------+------------+
      |label|sentence_replaced                                                        |
      +-----+----------------------------------+---------+---------------+------------+
      |0    |Apex Tool Group Armstrong nishanth hemanth Apex Tool Group               |
      |0    |Allen Apex Tool Group nishanth hemanth Allen                             |
      |1    |shivu Apex Tool Group nishanth                                           |
      |2    |shree shivu StanleyBlack                                                 |
      +-----+----------------------------------+---------+---------------+------------+

      Expected Output
      +-----+----------------------------------+---------+---------------+------------+
      |label| sentence_replaced                                                      |
      +-----+----------------------------------+---------+---------------+------------+
      |0    |Apex Tool Group Apex Tool Group nishanth hemanth Apex Tool Group         | 
      |1    |shivu Apex Tool Group nishanth                                           |
      |2    |shree shivu StanleyBlack                                                |
      +-----+----------------------------------+---------+---------------+------------+
```

I get such output when there is multiple replacements to do in a row.
Only Allen has been replaced with Apex Tool Group 
But not in Armstrong with Apex Tool Group in first row.
Label 0 should merge to get a single row as an output in the data.
 So that no redundancy should exist within the same Dataset Row 
Is there any other method which i must follow to get the proper output.? 
Or is this is limitation of UDF

Answer (score 0):

your "**contains**" function will create 2 rows out of "Allen Armstrong nishanth hemanth Allen", since 2 matches will be found: one on Allen, second one on Armstrong. That is why output has 4 instead of 3 expected.

"**replacewith**" reiterates after that over those 4 but with different replace string.

i.e. After **contains** you are getting:

```
"Allen Armstrong nishanth hemanth Allen", "Allen", "Apex Tool Group"
"Allen Armstrong nishanth hemanth Allen", "Armstrong","Apex Tool Group"
"shivu Armstrong nishanth", "Armstrong","Apex Tool Group"
"shree shivu DeWALT", "DeWALT","StanleyBlack"
```

And after **replacewith** - you receive your current output respectively.

Logic of contains needs to be reworked.

Consider deleting contains function at all, since `t1.replaceAll(t2, t3);` does the matching automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I had deleted contains function and executed the program. It was giving run-time exception. Again I tried to disable the contains function by making the return type to true, the outcome was 9 rows instead of 3. Is there any other better solution that needs to be worked? If you have any alternate solution kindly share it. Thanking You...

Comment: Since return t1.contains(t2); Searches the Input sentence with the string in L.H.S though it matches and replaces. But it does not traverse to second word in the L.H.S.in the given sentence. Although it again searches and replaces the word in the L.H.S if it's matches, that's the reason for getting 2 rows instead of 1 row

Comment: Is there any work should I need to try after deleting contains function? please provide me your suggestion!

Comment: UDF is executed for cells as 1-1. It does not have context to the whole context of column in your case. That is why with UDF you can replace only 1 word at a time. I would suggest reconsider wrapping replace springs as dataframe - make it as map and do replacement in your "replace with" using that map of values.

Comment: Well suggested comment. I'll try to work as you suggested. Thanking You vvinton